# Javascript button click on event to run a function

Tags: javascript

Ok, I have GCSE coursework to do based on this piece of code, although the code given to us to begin with(shown below) isn't correctly working, I believe it to be because the click on event isn't running the function that validates the information entered.

```
<head>
   <title>Exam entry</title>
   <script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
      function validateForm() {
          var result = true;
          var msg = ””;
          if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == ””) {
              msg += ”You must enter your name\n”;
              document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
              document.getElementById(‘name’).style.color = ”red”;
              result = false;
          }



          if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == ””) {
              msg += ”You must enter the subject\n”;
              document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
              document.getElementById(‘subject’).style.color = ”red”;
              result = false;
          }
          if (msg == ””) {
              return result;
          } {
              alert(msg)
              return result;
          }
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
   <form name=”ExamEntry” method=”post” action=”success.html”>
      <table width=”50%” border=”0”>
         <tr>
            <td id=”name”>Name</td>
            <td><input type=”text” name=”name” /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id=”subject”>Subject</td>
            <td><input type=”text” name=”subject” /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> <button type=”button” name=”Submit” value=”Submit” onclick=”return validateForm();” />"Submit"</button></td>
            <td> <button type=”button” name=”Reset” value=”Reset” />Reset</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</body>
```

This is the code now with all the updates, but it still fails to run the function :

```
 <head>
   <title>Exam entry</title>
 <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>

<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>
function validateForm() {
    var result = true;
    var msg = '';
    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == '') {
        msg += 'You must enter your name\n';
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color = 'red';
        result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == '') {
        msg += 'You must enter the subject\n';
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color = 'red';
        result = false;
    }

    if (msg == '') {
        return result;
    }

    alert(msg);
    return result;
}
</script>


<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
    <table width="50%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="subject" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" />
                Submit
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="Reset" value="Reset" />Reset</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: One problem may be the "smart quotes" in your code (`”`).  Try to replace those with "normal" quotes (`"`).  Also, don't use MS Word to for code ;)

Comment: I use notepad++ and i'll check now. edit - after replacing smart quotes it still doesnt work.

Comment: There's a few things missing in there. Check block `if (msg=="")`, it looks like there should be an `else`-block, but the keyword `else` itself is missing.
Also, the HTML is malformed. There is an extra closing `</button>` tag, where the opening `<button>` is self-closing. This is the root of the problem.

Comment: Make sure to also, replace `‘` with `'` (when you do `getElementById`).

Comment: I just got rid of the extra closing of button but it seems to not want to work still.

Comment: Fixing all your `”` and `‘` and adding the missing else and a missing semicolon on your alert, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fnSp2/

Comment: I copy and pasted the code from jsfiddle to see if it would work and I aint getting anything show up.

Comment: @Flux: You probably want to change your buttons from `type="button"` to `type="submit"` and `type="reset"`.

Comment: Alright thats done but I still cant get it to validate the information through the function
edit - It goes to the success page whether all the info is valid or not

Comment: @Flux: Then you are doing something wrong. The code works fine. There's something you are not telling us and nobody can guess what that is.

Comment: The code I have given to you in the second instance is exactly what I am using. I hit submit and nothing happens, I just have to assume it isnt running the function for some reason.

Comment: @Flux: Why is everything in the `head` now? If you don't understand that basics of how an HTML document is structured, you might want to go look through any of a number of HTML tutorials online.

Comment: That was merely a small typo correct Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/NDaqZ/)

**HTML**

```
 <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>

<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
    <table width="50%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="subject" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" />
                Submit
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="Reset" value="Reset" />Reset</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function validateForm() {
    var result = true;
    var msg = '';
    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == '') {
        msg += 'You must enter your name\n';
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color = 'red';
        result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == '') {
        msg += 'You must enter the subject\n';
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color = 'red';
        result = false;
    }

    if (msg == '') {
        return result;
    }

    alert(msg);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: When I put this togethor it doesnt work, I must be formatting it wrong, can you help me out ?

Comment: @Flux: How are you "formatting" it? It doesn't need formatting. Just cut and paste from the fiddle, putting the Javascript part in a `script` tag in the `head` and the html part in the `body`

Comment: @Flux the above code is your code formatted properly...all of your quotes where special and not standard.  Single and double quotes.  Beyond that your `alert(msg)` was missing a `;` then i removed the last `{` and `}` because it was just an else.

Comment: Ok , it tells me if its wrong, but it doesnt load up success.html now. Any ideas? I didnt exactly as you did when it came to the code from js fiddle.

Comment: @Flux: That's because you submit button isn't a submit button. How is the form supposed to know which button actually submits? Change it's type from `button` to `submit` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your quotes, and other errors, your code works below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Validator</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   </head>
   <body> 
      <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
      <form name="ExamEntry" id="ExamEntry" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
         <table width="50%" border="0">
            <tr>
               <td id="name">Name</td>
               <td>
                  <input id="nameField" type="text" name="name" >
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td id="subject">Subject</td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subjectField">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">"Submit"</button>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <button type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
      <script>
         function validateForm() {
            var result = true;
            var msg = "";
            if (document.getElementById("nameField").value === "") {
               msg += "You must enter your name\n";
               document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
               document.getElementById("name").style.color = "red";
               result = false;
            }

            if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value === "") {
               msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
               document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
               document.getElementById("subject").style.color = "red";
               result = false;
            }
            if (msg === "") {
               return result;
            }
            else {
               alert(msg);
               return result;
            }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We're doing the same thing. Make sure you are using Notepad and that you are saving it as a HTML file when you open it.

Hope this helped!
Also, could someone please explain what "action=success.html" does?

Comment: If you have a separate question, please ask it in a new question